# Which of the two sentences is correct? If both are, which one is better?

Tags: grammar, american-english

I want to know which sentence is better of the two?

> 1. I am not in mood to do debate.
> 2. I am not in a mood to debate.

Comment: (a) the idiom is _in **a/the** mood_; the article is required. (b) _Debate_ is a verb and thus _Do_-Support is not required. (1) uses no article and does use _Do_-Support. (2), however, is correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your first option. Let's go over them in some detail.

While *debate* can be both a noun and a verb, as a noun it is not something one would usually say can be *done*. If you want to use it as a noun and apply a verb that indicates a debate happening, you would use *to have*. In that context, *debate* is a countable noun, so it needs an article. That, you can talking about "*having a debate*", but not "*doing debate*"

The noun *mood* can be used in a manner that is countable, or it can be used in a manner that is uncountable. When you talk about someone's mood using the preposition *in*, it is countable. Thus, you cannot be "*in mood*", but you can be "*in a mood*" or, in certain situations "*in the mood*". The definite article suggests that there is one specific mood (or quality of mood) in question.

So, we can modify that sentence to be grammatical, and we get

> "I'm not in the mood to have a debate."

(Explaining why it's *the* mood, rather than *a* mood, is difficult; I suspect it's just one of those things you need to learn. However, in this case it wouldn't seem especially weird to use *a* - it's just not how a native speaker of the dialects I'm familiar with would do it.)

Your second option is much more nearly correct. That uses *debate* as a verb, qualifying *mood* and creating the noun phrase "*mood to debate*", meaning "mood suitable for debating". Again, however, that should take a definite article, giving us:

> "I'm not in the mood to debate."

This has exactly the same structure as the corrected version of your first option, it is just using *debate* as a verb, rather than *have*.

You can also use *for*, followed by a noun (including a mass noun), with *mood*, rather than a to-infinitive. In that case, we can use *debate* as a mass noun referring to the practice of debating, rather than a specific instance or event. That doesn't need an article:

> "I'm not in the mood for debate."

Or you can still use it with an article, indicating that it is used in its countable sense - meaning debate as a specific instance or event:

> "I'm not in the mood for a debate."

Or, where it's clear what the debate would be about, it can even have the definite article:

> "I'm not in the mood for the debate."

I hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

2 is better. 1 is missing important words.

Comment: Hi Ian, welcome to EL&U! Your answer would be better suited as a comment, so I have flagged it as 'not an answer'. If you would like to post an answer, please consider **editing** and **improving** your post. It would also be worth checking out how to answer well in the [help center.](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/325284)